# Joomla URL format for custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, sh404sef, non-sef-url

How can I get URL format given below for a custom component in Joomla 3 ( migrating / converting site from Joomla 1.5. Just for seo purpose, I want to keep url same for now )

> sitename.com/component/option,com_my_comp/Itemid,123/task,mytask

I have seen non-sef format like

> sitename.com/index.php?option=com_my_comp&Itemid=123&task=mytask

Or

sef url format like

> sitename.com/my-comp-page

For SEF URLs, I am using SH404SEF extension. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sef_ext plugins.

In sh404sef find sef_ext folder and create com_my_comp.php file

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');

    // ------------------  standard plugin initialize function - don't change ---------------------------
    $sefConfig = &Sh404sefFactory::getConfig();
    $shLangName = '';
    $shLangIso = '';
    $title = array();
    $shItemidString = '';
    $dosef = shInitializePlugin($lang, $shLangName, $shLangIso, $option);
    if ($dosef == false)
    {
        return;
    }
    // ------------------  standard plugin initialize function - don't change ---------------------------

    $title[] = 'my-comp-page';


    shRemoveFromGETVarsList('view');
    shRemoveFromGETVarsList('id');
    shRemoveFromGETVarsList('option');
    shRemoveFromGETVarsList('lang');
    shRemoveFromGETVarsList('task');



// ------------------  standard plugin finalize function - don't change ---------------------------
if ($dosef)
{
    $string = shFinalizePlugin($string, $title, $shAppendString, $shItemidString, (isset($limit) ? $limit : null),
        (isset($limitstart) ? $limitstart : null), (isset($shLangName) ? $shLangName : null), (isset($showall) ? $showall : null),
        $suppressPagination = true);
}
// ------------------  standard plugin finalize function - don't change ---------------------------
?>
```

With shRemoveFromGETVarsList you can remove any parameter added to url.

It's not a good idea use comma character in url, to get something like your first url:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$Itemid = $jinput->getInt('Itemid');

$title[] = 'option_'.$option;
$title[] = 'Itemid_'.$Itemid;
$title[] = 'task_'.$task;
```

If you want to use comma, you can enable it, in sh404sef configuration panel, in "Strip characters" option.

Answer (score 0):

you can use redirect with params:

> site.com/blog?limitstart=0 to site.com/blog

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^limitstart=0
RewriteRule ^blog http://site.com/blog? [R=301,L]
```